Jfrog Artifactory unable to connect to database
I'm running AlmaLinux 9.5 and have installed jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.98.9-79809900.x86_64 from rpm
Installed postgresql-server-13.16-1.el9_4.x86_64

installed:
openjdk 17.0.13 2024-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.13.0.11-1) (build 17.0.13+11-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.13.0.11-1) (build 17.0.13+11-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

I've downloaded postgresql-42.7.4.jar and dropped it in to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib/ as per the instructions.
I've created the artifactory database as per instructions
I've edited the system.yaml:
   allowNonPostgresql: false
   type: postgresql
   driver: org.postgresql.Driver
   url: jdbc:postgresql:10.213.53.51:5432/artifactory
   username: artifactory
   password: password

I've configured Postgres to accept connections from anywhere (confirmed with Beekeeper studio from another computer) and can connect using the artifactory user using psql.
As far as I can see, everything should be good, but in console.log I'm seeing:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database
"10.213.53.51:5432/artifactory" does not exist

I've downloaded sqlline to test the connection and get:

$ java -jar sqlline-1.12.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -u
jdbc:postgresql:10.213.53.51:5432/artifactory -u artifactory -p
password scan complete in 0ms No known driver to handle "artifactory"
sqlline version 1.12.

I get the feeling something is amiss with the jdbc driver, but have run out of ideas.
Thanks, Steve

Ahhh.... changed url to:
url: jdbc:postgresql://10.213.53.51:5432/artifactory
... and that seems to have worked. Every day's a school day.
